# Command block "Done button" not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image]

[image]

When I click done it just changes the command block type.
Same for when I click cancel it just changes if it's conditional or not

Im not quite sure if its from me playing on lunar client
edit: ^ That is why ^